# How to use a custom loss function in a Neural Network with MLPClassifier Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, loss-function

I would like to use a custom loss function to train a neural network in scikit learn; using MLPClassifier. I would like to give more importance to larger values. Therefore, I would like to use something like the mean square error but multiplying the numerator by y. Thus, it would look like :

1/n∑y(yi-y(hat)i)^2

Here is the code of my model:

```
mlp10 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100,50,25,10), max_iter=1000, 
random_state=42)
mlp10.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How can I modify the loss function ?

Comment: Using MSE for classification is generally considered a bad idea, that's why MLPClassifier uses cross-entropy.

Comment: My dataset contains a lot of smaller values (0, 0.5, 1 , 1.5 ) and fewer bigger values (>8). I want to predict correctly those bigger values. If the model predicts 5 and the real value is 0 or 2 per example, I do not mind, However, if the model predicts 2 and the real value is 14, this is very costly. Therefore, I was thinking to modify the loss function, but there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can modify the loss function directly as there is no parameter for it in the construction of the classifier and the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) explicitly specifies that it's optimizing using the log-loss function. If you're willing to be a bit flexible, you might be able to get the effect you're looking for simply by an transform of the `y` values before training and then use the inverse transform to recover the predicted `y`s after testing.

For instance, mapping `y_prime = transform(y)` and `y = inverse_transform(y_prime)` on each value where you define `transform` and `inverse_transform` as:

```
def transform(y):
    return y ** 2

def inverse_transform(y_prime):
    return math.sqrt(y_prime)
```

would cause larger values of `y` to have more influence in the training. Obviously you could experiment with different transforms to see what works best for your use-case. The key is just to make sure that `transform` is superlinear.

Before training you'd need to do:

```
y_train = map(transform, y_train)
```

And after calling `predict`:

```
y_predict = model.predict(x)
y_predict = map(inverse_transform, y_predict)
```

Comment: I am not able to train. I have an error message: "Singleton array array(<map object at 0x7fc886c50e10>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection." I am not familiar with map...But after doing `y_train = map(transform, y_train)`. If I print y_train, I obtain _ <map object at 0x7fc886c50e10> _ ,

Comment: Ah, it’s a python 2/3 difference in what map returns. Try np.array(map(transform, y_train)) instead

Comment: Is there any advantages using `map(transform`compared to simply use `np.power(target,2)` ; target is simply a df that contains my y,

Comment: That should work too. Then use `np.power(target, 0.5)` on the predictions

Comment: If instead of training my neural network with `1/n∑y(yi-y(hat)i)^2` I simply calculate it with the prediction from my normal train neural network and the true y. The goal will then be to compare different models and the one that will have a smaller value for this metric will be the one able to better predict higher values. Is it something logical to do?

Comment: I don't think you're likely to get models that are trained with much extra weight to higher ys.